# What does the id of a literal represent in python?

Tags: python

For example, what do things like `id(1)` and `id(1.0)` mean? I get that literally it means the `id` of the integer 1 or the float 1.0, but obviously python doesn't start running with every integer and float assigned to a location in memory (!)

Comment: It doesn't represent anything. For small integers, the id is just the integer's value, not a memory address.

Comment: numbers have fixed IDs, not locations in memory.

Comment: All that matters is that it's distinct from any other object's id.

Comment: IDs are implementation-specific and don't have to represent anything. In CPython, they happen to represent the memory address of an object. Does the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) not have enough info for you? "`Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value. CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.`"

Comment: The *hash* of a small integer is the integer; the id (in CPython) is (or is derived from) a memory address.